# what should be the initial dataset from millions of data points for stock line highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highchartstock

I want to prepare a line stock highchart like this example : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/lazy-loading

In the given example, when you load the chart for the first time, it calls `https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-historical.json` and fetches some points, to be precise 0-165 records (if you check the network tab and ajax call). At a same time `All` option is selected in the time range tool.

If you drill down further or go for any specific time range, it will bring more data always from the server.

**Question**: If you have millions of data points, consider from 2000 to 2022 years, then for `All` option, what are you going to display. what should be the initial data set or result or filter ?

**NOTE**: I will have millions of data points from 2000 to 2022 years going forward. When I load the chart for the first time, out of these millions points, what should come back from the server ?

**Just for your reference, you can check example of time series data that I'm going to have in `mock-data=>i.js` folder/file which is NOT being used anywhere in below example as of now.**

Highcharts 1.7 million points example :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wng4y6?file=index.js

*P.S.* : I'm new to stockhighcharts and I don't seem to find any proper explanation anywhere. Trying to reach out to the community for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side data grouping should be done based on the range for with you are trying to group the data, so All means nothing - however, in your case this will be 2 years.

For the data grouping you might also consider the chart size (this is done by default for a dataGrouping feature running client-side in Highcharts Stock). When relevant information is passed to the server it should return a set of grouped data points.

About grouping logic you can find more in the api options where is present method of approximation inside a group.
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.area.dataGrouping.approximation

Comment: You can check this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289307/what-should-be-onload-dataset-for-stock-highcharts-with-multiple-lines` where I have tried out something but of course it is not right implementation. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Sending this much data to highcharts to be processed is asking for issues.  I highly recommend making a local highcharts server (something they support) and have this done within your system.  [See it here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)

This is very important when it comes to security as well (if your data is sensitive), having it race across the internets to highcharts and then sent back to you leaves it open to the world.

From here, you can also specify the start and end time of each render, and have that change based on user input. Personally I would generally display the last 5 days or something, and then if someone wanted to, they could pull the slider all the way back for the last significant amount of time.

But, to answer your question, when you send a data object to highcharts, either local server or the highcharts server,  you will get a base64 image back that you can directly imbed in your UI.